# Apache NIFI PutHiveStreaming Issue

Tags: java, hive, apache-nifi

I am using the NIFI PutHiveStreaming processor to write records into HDFS and I keep running into this issue. I am not able to make much of it because it seems as if I have adhered to all the configuration requirements. Any pointers from someone has successfully resolved this issue? (Nifi - 1.4.0 and Hive - 2.3.3)

```
2018-04-18 09:03:49,997 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] hive.metastore Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://hive-metastore:9083
2018-04-18 09:03:49,999 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] hive.metastore Connected to metastore.
2018-04-18 09:03:50,486 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.h.h.m.RetryingMetaStoreClient MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
2018-04-18 09:03:51,487 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] hive.metastore Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://hive-metastore:9083
2018-04-18 09:03:51,491 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] hive.metastore Connected to metastore.
2018-04-18 09:03:51,505 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=1b8f6a4a-e456-3c2b-74be-bc9a0927a43b] Failed to create HiveWriter for endpoint: {metaStoreUri='thrift://hive-metastore:9083', database='default', table='bi_events_identification_carrier', partitionVals=[2018, 3, 28] }: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://hive-metastore:9083', database='default', table='bi_events_identification_carrier', partitionVals=[2018, 3, 28] }
org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://hive-metastore:9083', database='default', table='bi_events_identification_carrier', partitionVals=[2018, 3, 28] }
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.(HiveWriter.java:79)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveUtils.makeHiveWriter(HiveUtils.java:46)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.makeHiveWriter(PutHiveStreaming.java:968)
```

Caused by: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$TxnBatchFailure: Failed acquiring Transaction Batch from EndPoint: {metaStoreUri='thrift://hive-metastore:9083', database='default', table='bi_events_identification_carrier', partitionVals=[2018, 3, 28] }
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.nextTxnBatch(HiveWriter.java:264)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.(HiveWriter.java:73)
    ... 24 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.TransactionError: Unable to acquire lock on {metaStoreUri='thrift://hive-metastore:9083', database='default', table='bi_events_identification_carrier', partitionVals=[2018, 3, 28] }
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransactionImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:578)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransaction(HiveEndPoint.java:547)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.nextTxnBatch(HiveWriter.java:261)
    ... 25 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)

I have set the concurrency and txn parameters in hive-site.xml as well.

Comment: `transport.TTransportException` is like generic error exception that indicates something is not right with the HiveServer. Can you check if there is anything on interest in your hive log?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman: You were right! I was able to get more out of the hive-metastore logs:
<pre><code>
2018-04-18T12:55:09,922 ERROR [pool-9-thread-9]: metastore.RetryingHMSHandler (RetryingHMSHandler.java:invokeInternal(204)) - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected DataOperationType: UNSET agentInfo=Unknown txnid:3
</pre></code>

Comment: You should add what you found as an answer to your own question! That way people who stumble on this question later can learn from your experience.

Comment: Are you using Apache NiFi and Apache Hive, or a vendor-specific version of either?

Comment: @mattyb I am using Apache NIFI and Apache Hive. Not using any vendor specific versions.

Comment: @Nathan I agree. I will do that if I find a solution.

Comment: That version of NiFi is 1.2.1, it may not be compatible with Hive 2.x

Comment: @mattyb Goodness. Are you aware of any docs which refer to the version compatibility? 

I will try and build NIFI 1.4 with hive.version=1.2.1 and give this a go.

Comment: Sorry I meant NiFi 1.4.0 uses Hive 1.2.1, which apparently is not compatible with Hive 2.3.3

Comment: @mattyb So it seems I should try using Hive 1.2.1 and see how things look. I will update the thread today with how that works out!

Comment: Any solution in this matter ?I am using storm-hive to write streaming data and getting similar error `2018-06-08T00:01:25,899 ERROR [pool-13-thread-197([])]: metastore.RetryingHMSHandler (RetryingHMSHandler.java:invokeInternal(204)) - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected DataOperationType: UNSET agentInfo=Unknown txnid:94346`

Comment: @mattyb I don't if this is the right forum to ask this; since you are one of the committers to Apache Nifi,  is version 1.7 compatible with Hive 2.3 (or is it only 3.0)

Comment: Version 1.7 has two sets of Hive processors/services. One is the original set of Hive 1 processors (although I believe they work against a Hive 2 server), and one is the set of Hive 3 processors. However Apache NiFi does not include the Hive 3 bundle in the distribution (due to its size), instead you have to build the NAR yourself and drop it into your distribution. Also vendor distributions (such as HDF 2.3) do include the Hive 3 bundle by default.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Btw, I have tested Nifi 1.7 with Hive 2.3.2, and the "Unable to connect to Metastore endpoint" exist.